# How to use Nuxt Context to call Axios request with param

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

so I'm trying to get my Axios to do a get request with a param that'll end the url in

```
'/?user= {id}'
```

the id is passed in by my loggedInUser.id from Vuex. I know that async functions won't accept 'this' inside the call so I included store as a parameter. Something's still off with how I passed the data around thought I think. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

```
  

    import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
       
       export default {
         computed: {
           ...mapGetters(["loggedInUser"])
         },
         head() {
           return {
             title: "Actors list"
           };
         },
         components: {
           EditProfile
         },
         async asyncData({ store }) {
           try {
             const body = { data: store.getters.loggedInUser.id };
             const { actors } = await $axios.$get(`/api/v1/actors/`, {
               params: {
                 user: body
               }
             });
       
             return { actors };
           } catch (e) {
             return { actors: [] };
           }
         },
         data() {
           return {
             actors: []
           };
```

**Edit**

I got it to work when I removed the data: from 'const body' and removed the brackets as well around 'actor'

```
    try {
      const body = store.getters.loggedInUser.id;
      const actors = await $axios.$get(`/api/v1/actors/`, {
        params: {
          user: body
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your `params` from [Context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context#params).

`Context` is available in special nuxt lifecycle areas like `asyncData`, `fetch`, `plugins`, `middleware` and `nuxtServerInit`.

Answer (score -1):

In Nuxt, with asyncData hook you can get query parameters from the route context key.

Please read the Nuxt.js Context documentation. [The context provides additional objects/params from Nuxt to Vue components](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context)

With your-domain/?user=wonderman

```
asyncData({ route: { query: queryParams} }) {},
```

variable queryParams is an object:

```
{ user: "wonderman" }
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's quite what I want. Using route: would mean using Vue router to redirect right? I'm looking to pass in the queryparam to $Axios.get in order to display stuff on a page.